# Node/Express Routing issue - invoking incorrect path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

Everything seems to be working fine, however when attempting to reach '/posts/new' I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null" referencing '/routes/posts.js:24' which is in the '/:title' GET method.  Any ideas why?

'routes/posts.js'

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('posts');

/* posts displays*/
// posts index
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.find((err, posts) => {
        res.render(
            'posts/index', 
            {
                title: 'Get All the Posts!',
                posts: posts 
            }
        );
    });
});

// single post
router.get('/:title', (req, res) => {
    var query = {"title": req.params.title};
    Post.findOne(query, (err, post) => {
        res.render(
            'posts/post',
            {
                title: post.title,
                date: post.date,
                body: post.body
            }
        );
    });
});

/* posts new */
router
    // GET new posts route and form
    .get('/new', (req, res) => {
        res.render('posts/new', { title: 'Add a new Post' });
    })
    // POST new post data
    .post('/new', (req, res) => {
        new Post({
            title: req.body.title,
            date: req.body.date,
            body: req.body.body
        })
        // Save post to db 
        .save((err, post) => {
            res.redirect('/posts');
        });
    });

/* posts edit */
router
    // GET the post
    .get('/edit/:title', (req, res) => {
        var query = {'title': req.params.title};
        Post.findOne(query, (err, post) => {
            res.render(
                'posts/edit',
                {
                    title: post.title,
                    date: post.date,
                    body: post.body
                }
            );
        });
    })
    // PUT to update the post
    .put('/edit/:title', (req, res) => {
        var query = {'title': req.params.title};
        var update = {
            title: req.body.title,
            body: req.body.body
        };
        var options = {new: true};
        Post.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, (err, post) => {
            res.render(
                'posts/post',
                {
                    title: post.title,
                    date: post.date,
                    body: post.body
                }
            );
        });
    })
    // DELETE to delete a post
    .delete('/edit/:title', (req, res) => {
        var query = {'title': req.params.title};
        Post.findOneAndRemove(query, (err, posts) => {
            res.redirect('/');
        })
    });

module.exports = router;
```

'views/posts/new' with Swig:

```
{% extends '../layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    <form method='post' action='/posts/new' class='form-posts'>
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name='title' class='form-posts-text' required>
        <label>Body</label>
        <input type="text" name='body' class='form-posts-body' required>
        <button type='submit' class='btn-submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So when you type a single character into the address bar it redirects immediately? Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the route for `/new` before the generic `/:title` root.

Because `/:title` is defined first, it gets called first if it matches (which it does). Since you have no post with the name "new", your database search comes up empty. You should probably have an error handler there. The error seems to be on the  line `title: post.title`.

If `/new` is defined first, it will get called if it matches. If it doesn't, the more generic `/:title` will be.

Comment: That did it, silly oversight, thank you.  Assumed lack of 'new' in a title in db would be considered prior but no reason why that would occur first.  Will implement error-checking.